# creating foreignObject in svg using javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, xhtml

I would like to create foreignObject in SVG using pure javascript.
I don't know why it doesn't work.
My foreign object is in a `<g>` element. And inside it is a simple div.

I tried using  `"requiredExtensions"` and `"xmlns"`
I thought that my div was somewhere outside the window but i checked `getBoundingClientRect().left;` and it is not.

My code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>SVG TEST</title>
<style>

</style>
<script>
    function init(){
        var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]; //Get svg element
        svg.setAttribute("xmlns","http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
        var g=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'g'); //Create a g element in SVG's namespace
        g.setAttribute("x",0); //Set g dat
        g.setAttribute("y",0); //Set g dat
        svg.appendChild(g);

        var newNode = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'foreignobject'); //Create a rect in SVG's namespace
        newNode.setAttribute("x",0); //Set rect data
        newNode.setAttribute("y",0); //Set rect data
        newNode.setAttribute("width","180"); //Set rect data
        newNode.setAttribute("height","80"); //Set rect data
        g.appendChild(newNode);

        var f=newNode;

        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');     
        var divIdName = "div_1";
        newDiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
        newDiv.innerHTML = "First";
        f.appendChild(newDiv);
    }   
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">

    <svg id="svg" width="300px" height="300px"/>  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

SVG is case sensitive so you must create a foreignObject element and not a foreignobject element.

There are some other minor things wrong too:

- setting an xmlns attribute will do nothing
- `<g>` elements don't have x and y attributes
- x and y on foreignObject elements default to 0 so those can be omitted too